# Find the multiplicity of $z_0$ as a zero of the composition function $f\circ g$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ , $f(z_0)=0$ with multiplicity $m$ , $g(z_0)=0$ with multiplicity $n$. What is the multiplicity of $z_0$ as a zero of the composition function $f\circ g$ ?

From given condition , we can write $f$ and $g$ as

$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^mh_1(z)$$ and$$g(z)=(z-z_0)^nh_2(z)$$where , $h_1(z)$ and $h_2(z)$ are analytic and $h_1(z_0)\not=0$ and $h_2(z_0)\not=0$.

Now , $$(f\circ g)(z)=f(g(z))=f\left((z-z_0)^nh_2(z)\right)$$

$$=\left\{(z-z_0)^nh_2(z)\right\}^mh_1\left((z-z_0)^nh_2(z)\right)$$

> From here what can I say about the order of zero ofd $f\circ g$ at $z_0$ ?

Comment: With the above conditions, $z_0$ is not necessarily a zero of $f\circ g$.

Comment: I think you want $g(z_0) = z_0$.

Comment: @  Amitai Yuval) From my last line in question , it is clear that $z_0$ is a zero of $f\circ g$..

Comment: $(f\circ g)(z_0) = f(g(z_0)) = f(0)$. You want maybe that $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $0$, or that $g$ attains the value $z_0$ with multiplicity $n$ at $z_0$.